# python keeps saying the variables are not defined in a variable, depending on the path the user goes on for a flow chart. How do I fix this?

Tags: python

```
answer=input("do you have an existing cell phone plan? Reply yes or no in lowercase")
if answer==choice2:
 response=input("are you considering a CONTRACTUAL or HYBRID cell phone? Write the options in capitals")
if response not in cell:
        print("consider a prepaid cell phone")
if answer==choice1:
    cool=input("do you have a free upgrade?")
if cool==choice2:
    print(response)
if response not in cell:
    print ("consider a prepaid cell phone")
if cool==choice1:
    print ("upgrade your new phone")
```

when used error comes up :
 I think i use too much if statements but i'm not sure (in year 10 GCSE)

```
do you have an existing cell phone plan? Reply yes or no in lowercasees
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/richard/Desktop/keseana/pictures/buying a phone.py", line 23, in <module>
    if response not in cell:
NameError: name 'response' is not defined
```

Comment: The issue is that `response` is only defined in the first `if` statement, so if that's false, `response` won't be defined for any of the other `if` statements.

Comment: I usually define them in the very beginning by assigning them to None, and then checking the value before using them.

Comment: In this case, why don't you just nest the `if`s?

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning None to response before the statements. Try the following (I haven't tested it)

```
answer=input("do you have an existing cell phone plan? Reply yes or no in lowercase")
response = None
if answer==choice2:
 response=input("are you considering a CONTRACTUAL or HYBRID cell phone? Write the options in capitals")
if response not in cell:
        print("consider a prepaid cell phone")
if answer==choice1:
    cool=input("do you have a free upgrade?")
if cool==choice2:
    print(response)
if response not in cell:
    print ("consider a prepaid cell phone")
if cool==choice1:
    print ("upgrade your new phone")
```

The reason your one wouldn't work, was response exists only if the first if statement was passed, else response doesn't exist. Assigning None to it should stop this.